# how to get userdefined attribute in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to just fetch the user defined attribute data  using jquery:

Simple code:

```
var a = 'id';
var patienttype = $a.attr('patientType');
```

I WANT TO CALL THE RESPECTIVE TEXTBOX ie 'a' and then call its corresponding user defined attribute ie patienttype.

I am not sure of the syntax and couldn't understand how can that be done.
I tried:

```
$a.attr('patientType'); //undefined
$('#a').attr('patientType') //output:undefined
```

Comment: var a = 'id';                                                        var patienttype = $a.attr('patientType'); alert(patientype);

Comment: did you try `$('#' + a).attr('patientType');` also do note that `patientType` is not a valid html attribute

Comment: It seems you are looking for the ID selector: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/. You'd probably also benefit of reading this: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/.

Comment: Please add some more details, and HTML code.  A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case would be helpful.

Comment: @FelixKling.. I don't think so.. Looks like OP has even tried `$('#a').`

Comment: I just did.. as PSL said -------                                                           var patienttype = $('#'+p).attr('patientType');alert(patienttype);

Comment: @Sushanth: Well, together with some string concatenation.

Comment: Without a sample HTML input data the code is mostly impossible to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("Selector") //selects an DOM object
```

Let's say that we have an label with id = lbl1 and if we want to add our defined attribute to it we can use the data-attributename

```
<label id="lbl1" data-custom="aCustomAttr"></label>
```

Now using the jquery to select the label custom attribute

```
$("#lbl1").attr("data-custom"); // This will yield aCustomAttr
```